# Trying to remove all spaces from a field in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation

I have this line of code in WordPress:

```
a href="http://domain.com/<?php echo $member['ut_member_name']; ?>"
```

I want it to displace the field WITHOUT any of the spaces.

For example: http://domain.com/tomjones

The field is originally saved as "Tom Jones".

Any idea how I can do this...??

Thanx in advance.

Comment: str_replace(" ","", $member['ut_member_name']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? `strtolower(str_replace(" ","", $member['ut_member_name']));`

This will remove all space and make all characters to lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

try str_replace

```
$member_name = str_replace(" ","", $member['ut_member_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the existing wordpress functions. Check at below link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes